# Install Nagios plugins

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, nagios

Can somebody please show me how to install this nagios plugin that checks if your servers require winodws updates?

http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Uncategorized/Operating-Systems/Windows-NRPE/Check-Windows-Updates/details

I am on Ubuntu 10.04 with Nagios V3. I followed the nagios quick install guide to get Nagios running.

edit: I have NSclient++ installed on the monitored servers.

Comment: Thank you foe the reply's. I have learnt a great deal about NRPE the last weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each server that you want to monitor you have to download the script and enable external scripts, you can add that line (shown in your link) to your NSC.ini

```
commandwindows_updates=c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe //NoLogo //T:120 c:\nrpe_nt\plugins\check_windows_updates.wsf /w:0 /c:1
```

Always be careful of scripts and at the very list skim through them.

Then on your nagios installation create a new service check or a new command on your commands.cfg.

It should look like (if you set it as a command)

```
define command{
       command_name    check_updates_nt
       command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p 5666 -c commandwindows_updates
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll copy that script to the NRPE plugins directory on each server that you want it to run on and modify the command if necessary to reflect the correct path.

Then, just create a new command with the code in the link that you provided.

NAGIOS is pretty thoroughly documented, you should take a look it more than just the Quick Start Guide.